# Re-attach Canon Speedlite Wide Panel (diffuser)

Tags: canon, flash, repair, renting

I am renting a Canon Speedlite 580EX II.

I had the pull-out Wide Panel (aka diffuser) out and, and when I went to push it back in I noticed that it was very, very loosely attached to its little black bar. Then, it popped off in my hand.

So, I can put the panel back on its mount fine, with the little spring in its notch and the little nubs on the ends in their holes, but it still feels really loose. I can push the panel back into the flash unit, but it pops off when I pull it out again.

I see in the [manual](http://downloads.canon.com/cpr/software/camera/Speedlite-580EXII.pdf) that it warns me not to use excessive force (which I wasn't...) or the panel can detach.

So, can anyone tell me how to re-attach the panel so that it stays tight? Nothing appears to be at all broken, as best I can tell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the little nubs that make the panel stay in place had worn down and finally gotten to the point where they were to small to reliably hold the panel in place.

The rental place swapped my unit for a working one.

Comment: Glad to hear that worked out okay, and thanks for sharing the results. I can't imagine that happening with the diffuser panel on my own flash for many, many years, but I guess those rental units get a lot more constant use.